# Ordinal of injectivity for a smooth regular curve with a finite arc-length

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, set-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Let $\gamma: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^d$ defined by $$\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\dots,\gamma_d(t)) $$ be a smooth (i.e., $\gamma\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}))$ and regular ($\gamma^\prime(t)\neq \vec 0$) curve with finite arc-length.

Define a possibly transfinite partition $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_\Omega\le b\}$ of an initial segment of $[a,b]$ by setting $x_0=a$, and then
$$
x_m= \sup \{t\in(x_{m-1},b]\mid \forall s\in [a,x_{m-1}],\gamma_j(t)\neq\gamma_j(s) \quad \forall 1\le j\le d-1\},
$$
whenever $\Omega\ge m>0$ is a successor ordinal, and 
$$
x_m= \sup \{t\in[x_m',b]\mid \forall s\in [a,x_m'),\gamma_j(t)\neq\gamma_j(s) \quad \forall 1\le j\le d-1\},
$$ 
whenever $\Omega\ge m$ is a limit ordinal, where $x_m'=\sup\{x_l\mid l<m\}$. The ordinal $\Omega $ is the largest ordinal for which these definitions make sense, that is, the sets over which suprema are computed are non-empty, and we have not reached $ b $ yet. Note that we can have $x_\Omega <b $.

Roughly speaking, this partition divides $\gamma(t)$ into injective graphs in respect to last coordinate. The ordinal $\Omega$ indicates how long the partition goes, that is, we define $x_m$ for as long as possible, and the construction eventually terminates when we reach $b$, and $\Omega$ is the subindex ordinal that $b$ was assigned.

My question is "how large can $\Omega$ be?". Clearly, $\Omega<\omega_1$ since there is no order preserving embedding of $\omega_1$ into $\mathbb R$. Can we find a curve $\gamma$ with $\Omega \ge \omega$? Can we bound this ordinal?

Comment: @BenMcKay But the cardinality of $P$ won't be infinite.

Comment: @BenMcKay also I can't see why it has a finite arc-length.

Comment: Each point $t \in P$ is a point at which $\gamma(t)=\gamma(a)$. If there are infinitely many, they accumulate at at point $t \in P$ at which $\gamma'(t)=0$.

Comment: If you allow $\gamma'(b)=0$ and only want $C^{\infty}[a,b)$, make $\gamma$ start at the origin, turn around circle at unit speed, then around a smaller circle, tangent to the first at the origin, and so on. This only gives $C^2$ $\gamma$. Replace the circles by a smooth loop that has infinite order tangency to the horizontal axis at the origin, and repeat with every smaller copies of that loop, shrinking fast enough to get finite total length.

Comment: @BenMcKay but the Hawaiian earring you describe is in $C^\infty[a,b)$, isn't it? How replacing it with smooth loops helps? Another question: What is order of tangency ? However, it's only an example for $|P|=\aleph_0$ as far as I understood. Can we construct something similar but now with cardinality of continuum ?

Comment: If the points of $P$ have an accumulation point in $(a,b)$, then $\gamma'(t)=0$ at that accumulation point. So $P$ strikes every compact subinterval of $(a,b)$ in a discrete set, i.e. in a finite set. Hence $P$ is countable.

Comment: $[a,b]$ is compact so every infinite subset has an accumulation point.

Comment: @BenMcKay thanks. One last thing: why $P$ strikes every subinterval in a discrete set?

Comment: A discrete subset is a subset without accumulation points. A discrete subset of a compact set is finite.

Comment: @BenMcKay I meant why there are no accumulation points in this intersection.

Comment: Also, why $\gamma^\prime(t)=0$?

Comment: $\gamma'(t)$ is the limit of the differences $(\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t))/h$ along any sequence of values $h \to 0$. So if $\gamma(t+h)=\gamma(t)$ along an infinite sequence of values of $h \to 0$, then $\gamma'(t)=0$.

Comment: @BenMcKay Why such a sequence (i.e. $\gamma(t+h_n)=\gamma(t+h_{n+1})=\dots$, $\quad\forall n>n_0$) exists?

Comment: Suppose that $P$ is not discrete. Then it has an accumulation point $t$. Such a point is the limit of a sequence of distinct points of $P$. Write those points as $t+h_1, t+h_2, \dots$. By definition of $P$, $\gamma(t+h_n)=\gamma(a)$ is constant in $n$.

Comment: @BenMcKay Pardon but I had a mistake defining $P$ in this way. As I wrote under, I meant dividing $\gamma$ to functions. Sorry if that changes the question too much. According to the fixed definition of $P$, does still $\gamma^\prime(t)=0$?

Comment: I do not understand how you want to continue past the naturals in your construction. I assume $x_\omega$ is defined with respect to the supremum of the $x_m$, $m\in\mathbb N$, and similarly at each limit stage you encounter. If that's the intention, you are producing a well-ordered subset of the reals, so it is countable, and the question would not quite be one of cardinality but rather to identify the ordinal corresponding to the supremum of the order types that can be obtained this way. Instead of $\mathfrak c$, you probably want to talk of $\omega_1$.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo That was exactly my intention. Can we bound this ordinal? Can we construct for every ordinal a corresponding curve $\gamma$?

Comment: I cannot parse this question despite several edits. There is a $t$ which should be a $s$, and I don't see what $n$ is. Also, I have never seen $\aleph_0$ used to denote an ordinal. There might be others, but you should gve more care to your question if you expect answers.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I revised the question.

Comment: I made a new edit. I believe the version I left is what you intended.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what role $d$ is playing in all this. I think you have not quite said what you have in mind, because leaving $d$ out in the definition of the $x_i$ looks arbitrary at the moment (and presumably forces us to have $d>1$, for no good reason other than to make sense of the definitions). My suggestion would be to let $d=1$ and adjust notation a bit (in particular, I would even suggest to let $[a,b]=[0,1]$). Also, what exactly is it that you mean when you say that the $\gamma_i$ define the arc-length of $\gamma$?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo I want $\gamma$ to be some curve (e.g. $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t$). We can assume (wlog) $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $d=2$. I meant that $\gamma$ has a finite arc-length (it has nothing with $\gamma_i$).

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I still don't see what role $\gamma_d$ is playing in all this.

Comment: And why do we care that the $\gamma_i$ are never zero?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Maybe I'm wrong but suppose you take $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\gamma(t)=(1,t)$, $\gamma_1^\prime\equiv 0$ and $P=[0,1]$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. One of your assumptions is that $\gamma_1'$ never vanishes.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. $\gamma_i$ can be zero in some points. I meant that the derivative cannot be identically zero in some component.

Comment: The question is still missing something. The sup could be on the empty set, I doubt the closed intervals are really what is meant, there is no obvious link between the formal definition and injectivity, and the last coordinates presently only have as a consequence to make the regularity assumption vacuous. After that many edits and tentative to make sense out of it, I think already too much time have been spent on this by others than the asker. I vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is that there is no better bound than $\Omega=\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal. I'll sketch the solution for $d=1$, I believe the others are similar. For any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is an order-preserving embedding of $\alpha$ into $[a, b]$ with closed image $I$. We can then take any continuous function $\gamma$ on $[a, b]$ satisfying $\gamma^{-1}(\{0\})=I$ (it's not hard to also make $\gamma$ smooth and regular); the associated $\Omega$ will then be at least $\alpha$.